# How can I use value_type from std::unordered_map(and probably other containers)

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, containers, unordered-map

I'm writing lambda to operate on std::unordered_map values

```
unordered_map<int, string> map;
auto lambda = [](pair<int, string> value) {/**/};
```

Is it a way to somehow use value_type instead of writing pair<int, string>?

And in general how `value_type` could be used?

Comment: `unordered_map<int, string>::value_type`, or `decltype(map)::value_type`. BTW the `value_type` would be `pair<const int, string>`.

Comment: did you try something? Frankly, it is a little strange that you know about `value_type` but ask how to use it. This would be more answerable if you explained what you tried or what problem you encountered

Comment: fwiw, since C++14 `[](auto value) {/**/};` might be an option